# How to set Home.php as my index page in PHP?

Tags: cpanel

I have a website created in PHP.

After uploading Home.php via ftp, I have noticed I need to explicitly type `www.example.com/Home.php` for it to display correctly.

I don't want to use [example.com/Home.php](https://example.com/home.php)

I want to display the Home.php page by simply going to example.com

Comment: Rename `Home.php` to `index.php` and then reload the page.